# Conjugated diene + Na in liq.NH3

Tags: organic-reduction

I learned that alkynes gets reduced on addition of $\ce{Na}$ in liquid $\ce{NH3}$ to form alkenes (which is not further reduced). Recently I came across a reaction where a conjugated diene was treated with $\ce{Na}$ in liquid $\ce{NH3}$ .The product was what you would get by 1,4 adding $\ce{H2}$ in the conjugated diene.

Is this reaction correct? If yes ,then what makes it more reactive than an ordinary alkene?

Comment: Thanks!!It does not entirely answer my question."then what makes it more reactive than an ordinary alkene?"-This part to be more specific.

Comment: I think it's the stability of intermediate radical.

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne yes!can be as it forms a cyclic intermediate with Na.